# print each Network set in separate same group

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv-simple

Currently my `csv input` looks like below:

```
network_name,network_set
P1MSVmgmtvM,Data_NetworkSet_A
P1MSVvMotion,Data_NetworkSet_A
P2MSVmgmtvM,Data_NetworkSet_B
P2MSVvMotion,Data_NetworkSet_B
E1MSVEDGEiDMZRUE1,Edge_NetworkSet_A
E1MSVEDGEiEXPRUE1,Edge_NetworkSet_A
```

I want output like below: (for each network set, I want to display its associated network name)

```
Data_NetworkSet_A
 P1MSVmgmtvM
 P1MSVvMotion
Data_NetworkSet_B
 P2MSVmgmtvM
 P2MSVvMotion
Edge_NetworkSet_A
 E1MSVEDGEiDMZRUE1
 E1MSVEDGEiEXPRUE1
```

Comment: ...and what have you tried this far?

Comment: Actually it was a big csv file with lot of column values. I was able to seperate out mentioned network_set and network_name column using processLine () function, but could not understand the logic , how to compare and achieve desired output by ignoring duplicate network_set

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{seen[$2]=seen[$2]"\n "$1;} END{for(x in seen) print x, seen[x]}' infile
Data_NetworkSet_A
 P1MSVmgmtvM
 P1MSVvMotion
Data_NetworkSet_B
 P2MSVmgmtvM
 P2MSVvMotion
Edge_NetworkSet_A
 E1MSVEDGEiDMZRUE1
 E1MSVEDGEiEXPRUE1
```

---

In `seen[$2]=seen[$2]"\n "$1;`; means print a `\n`ewline-space, followed by first column value `$1` when it has same second column `seen[$2]=...` and append into the same key index `=seen[$2]...` and save the result in same key's value.

The [`END` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html#Using-BEGIN_002fEND), *awk* executing this block in end when all records/line read, and we used a for-loop to iterate over the array called *seen* and print the key first and the value of the key in next.

Comment: Thanks alot @afshin. You saved my day.  
I have a related query , if you can advice on same would be great..